# How to make these particles flow along this curve object?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, fcurves, particle-edit-mode

this is my first post here I'm kinda a newbie therefore pardon my ignorance. So there is this curve object I've imported as a svg file. I want to create some particles to flow along it. Since now I've tried both Curve Guide and Force but both doesn't seem to work. How do I do it? (Curve and instance object are in the same collection)

[image]
[image]

Comment: if u provide a blend file, i will have a look...

Comment: That would be great! Here's the blend file: https://we.tl/t-Zskj8cH8vT

The top one is just imported as svg and is a curve I'd like to use as curve guide. Bottom one (extruded one) is already converted to mesh

Comment: hello, have you been able to look around?

Comment: The curve edges form the object. How should the particles follow the curve? In which direction and on which path?

Comment: I want it to be totally random it doesn't matter which direction just little particles on the object